# Which has higher concentration?

Tags: mathematics

You have two containers with equal volume of mutually soluble liquids A and B.  You take a table spoon of A and pour it into B, **mix**, and then the same table spoon of B back into A.

Now which one has a higher concentration of the other liquid? **Why?** (assume no loss of volume when mixing)

Comment: This is an ***old*** puzzle — I remember seeing it over 30 years ago.

Comment: I can't believe this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: It is a duplicate, more than once. Here's one: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1833/how-much-red-sand-and-how-much-blue-sand [EDITED to add:] My previous comment was added automatically by voting-to-close; I didn't know it would do that. Anyway, here's another http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3333/water-glass-and-wine-glass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initially, the situation is like this:

```
                  ┌───────────────┬────────────────┬───────────────┐
                  │  Container 1  │      Spoon     │  Container 2  │
┌─────────────────┼───────────────┼────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ Total volume    │       V       │        0       │       V       │
│ Mass A          │       Ma      │        0       │       0       │
│ Concentration A │      Ma/V     │        -       │       0       │
│ Mass B          │       0       │        0       │       Mb      │
│ Concentration B │       0       │        -       │      Mb/V     │
└─────────────────┴───────────────┴────────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Taking 1 spoon of volume Vs from container 1

```
                  ┌───────────────┬────────────────┬───────────────┐
                  │  Container 1  │      Spoon     │  Container 2  │
┌─────────────────┼───────────────┼────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ Total volume    │      V-Vs     │        Vs      │       V       │
│ Mass A          │   Ma(V-Vs)/V  │     Ma*Vs/V    │       0       │
│ Concentration A │      Ma/V     │       Ma/V     │       0       │
│ Mass B          │       0       │        0       │       Mb      │
│ Concentration B │       0       │        0       │      Mb/V     │
└─────────────────┴───────────────┴────────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Pouring the spoon to container 2, assuming additive volumes,

```
                  ┌───────────────┬────────────────┬───────────────┐
                  │  Container 1  │      Spoon     │  Container 2  │
┌─────────────────┼───────────────┼────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ Total volume    │      V-Vs     │        0       │      V+Vs     │
│ Mass A          │   Ma(V-Vs)/V  │        0       │    Ma*Vs/V    │
│ Concentration A │      Ma/V     │        -       │ Ma*Vs/V(V+Vs) │
│ Mass B          │       0       │        0       │       Mb      │
│ Concentration B │       0       │        -       │   Mb/(V+Vs)   │
└─────────────────┴───────────────┴────────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Taking 1 spoon of volume Vs from container 2

```
                  ┌───────────────┬────────────────┬───────────────┐
                  │  Container 1  │      Spoon     │  Container 2  │
┌─────────────────┼───────────────┼────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ Total volume    │      V-Vs     │       Vs       │       V       │
│ Mass A          │   Ma(V-Vs)/V  │ Ma*Vs²/V(V+Vs) │  Ma*Vs/(V+Vs) │
│ Concentration A │      Ma/V     │  Ma*Vs/V(V+Vs) │ Ma*Vs/V(V+Vs) │
│ Mass B          │       0       │  Mb*Vs/(V+Vs)  │  Mb*V/(V+Vs)  │
│ Concentration B │       0       │    Mb/(V+Vs)   │   Mb/(V+Vs)   │
└─────────────────┴───────────────┴────────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Pouring the spoon to container 1, again with additive volumes,

```
                  ┌───────────────┬────────────────┬───────────────┐
                  │  Container 1  │      Spoon     │  Container 2  │
┌─────────────────┼───────────────┼────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ Total volume    │       V       │        0       │       V       │
│ Mass A          │  Ma*V/(V+Vs)  │        0       │  Ma*Vs/(V+Vs) │
│ Concentration A │   Ma/(V+Vs)   │        -       │ Ma*Vs/V(V+Vs) │
│ Mass B          │  Mb*Vs/(V+Vs) │        0       │  Mb*V/(V+Vs)  │
│ Concentration B │ Mb*Vs/V(V+Vs) │        -       │   Mb/(V+Vs)   │
└─────────────────┴───────────────┴────────────────┴───────────────┘
```

This time the math was a bit more difficult to do mentally. This is the mass of liquid A in container 1:

$M_a \frac{V-V_s}{V} + M_a \frac{V_s^2}{V(V+V_s)}
= M_a \frac{V^2-V_s^2}{V(V+V_s)} + M_a \frac{V_s^2}{V(V+V_s)}
= M_a \frac{V^2}{V(V+V_s)}
= M_a \frac{V}{V+V_s}
$

Therefore, the answer is

> Container 1 ends up having $M_b \frac{Vs}{V(V+V_c)}$ concentration of liquid B.
>  Container 2 ends up having $M_a \frac{Vs}{V(V+V_c)}$ concentration of liquid A.
>  So it depends.

- If liquid A is more dense than liquid B, i.e. $M_a > M_b$,

  > Then container 1 has lower concentration of B than container 2 has of A
- If liquid A is as dense as liquid B, i.e. $M_a = M_b$,

  > Then container 1 has the same concentration of B as container 2 has of A
- If liquid A is less dense than liquid B, i.e. $M_a < M_b$,

  > Then container 1 has higher concentration of B than container 2 has of A

Note I assumed [mass concentration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_concentration_(chemistry)), but the result would be the same for [molarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_concentration). They are the typical measures of concentration.

I think other answers say the concentrations are the same because they use strange measures like percentage of volumes or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can figure this out without using any math at all.

> The volume of the containers start as equal. We move one table spoon one way, then the other, so the volumes are still even.
> For any amount of liquid A in container B, there must have be moved an equal amount of liquid B to container A for this to be true.

Answer (score 0):

> They will each have the same concentration of the other. Let the amounts of A and B in the second spoonful be x and y, the original volume be V, and one tablespoon be T.
>  y = T-x, so the amounts in the first jar after the final mixing will be 
>  A: V-T+x (start with V, take away T, and then add x) 
> B: T-x
>  Meanwhile, the amount of A that remains in the mostly B jar is the remainder of the tablespoon, I.e. T-x, and the amount of B remaining in the jar is V-(T-x) = V-T+x 
> Thus, the ratios are the same.

Answer (score 0):

> They are the same 
> If you take the volume of each as V, concentrations of A and B and a table spoon as t 
>  
> After you move your A tbsp 
> B has a concentration of (A*t)/(V+t).
> This concentration won't change any more
>
> You move B back to A and 
> the concentration of A becomes (B'*t)/(V-t+t) 
> where B' = (B*V)/(V+t) which is the new concentration of B 
>  Then simplfy the expression and it becomes 
>  B*t/(V+t) 
>  
>  which is the same as the A concentration in B.

Answer (score 0):

No initial volume is given, so, let's assume that it doesn't matter and pick something convenient, say 2 tablespoons each.

When we add half of A to B, we get a 1/3:2/3 solution. One tablespoon of this contains 1/3 T of A, and 2/3 T of B. Adding that to the 1 T of A that's left, makes the A bottle 2A:1B, while the original B container is 1A:2B.

So, the amount of B that's in A is the same as the amount of A that's in B.

Comment: You've only proven it for one scenario, not all scenarios.